# Make a surface from vertices

Tags: three.js

I have an array of approx 1000 points in this format [x,y,z,color], points can be more or less. Currently I am rendering those points as a point cloud (THREE.Points()) but the points are not evenly spaced. So the resulting point cloud looks dense in some areas and irregular in other areas. Is there a way to build a surface out of those points with the color converting to a gradient?

I tried using THREE.ConvexGeometry but it seems to be ignoring the actual shape and only focusing on dense areas to form the surface. Surface can also be 3D, sadly I don't have the function to generate more points. Here is a sample image of how things are being done right now. I could increase point size but there is no single predefined point size which will work for all cases.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.[image: points rendered as a THREE.Points]

Comment: ConvexHull is intended to create a 3D shell around your points; if it isn't doing this you should report a bug. To preserve colors of the points as vertex colors on the hull, you'll need to either modify its code or re-apply average colors later. No built-in function exists for that; best to attempt it and ask on Stack Overflow if you run into issues.

Comment: Thanks Don for the response, I will try out Convexhull for a variet of cases n report if needed. Was wondering if a nearest neighbor algo existed to form triangles and color them as a gradient, add them to faces of a buffered geometry n show that buffered geom.

Comment: There might be a function like that yes (it's certainly possible), but I haven't seen an example in three.js yet. May need some trial and error.